# ɔ̃ does not exist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, key, keycode, phonetics

I was doing a simple program in JS to get a list of keyCodes for all french phoneme symbols in the International Phonetic Alphabet, and I realised that key like `ɔ̃` are actually considered as `ɔ` and `~`.

My code:

```
var s = "iuyaɑãoɔɔ̃eεɛ̃øœœ̃əfvszʃʒlrpbmtdnkgɲjwɲ"
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s.charCodeAt(i))
}
console.log(s.length)
```

The excpected output is a list of keycodes for each of the characters in the String.
So is there any charset that has tilde accents in it?

Comment: "Mandatory" background reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Yep, `ɔ̃` isn’t a Unicode code point, but a grapheme cluster — completely unrelated to JavaScript. See `Array.from("iuyaɑãoɔɔ̃eεɛ̃øœœ̃əfvszʃʒlrpbmtdnkgɲjwɲ".normalize("NFC"))` (Please read [Do NOT use `.split('')`](/a/38901550/4642212) and [`normalize`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)). What exactly do you expect and why? _“The expected output is a list of keycodes for each of the characters in the String”_ — What, do you believe, is the “key code” of `ɔ̃`? Why? Which standard have you researched that would support your reasoning?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't really know, but when I do `print(int('someRandomChar'));` in Java or Javascript, or in any other language I think, the output is always the same. Is this Unicode, or what?

Comment: _"or in any other language"_ In C and C++ it's usually ASCII, but it's implementation defined. No, the output isn't always the same. Even in the same programming language, you can get different results on different systems. In JavaScript, it's standardized, but don't expect same values in all programming languages.

Comment: _“So is there any charset that has tilde accents in it?”_ — I don’t think using anything other than Unicode and UTF-8 is appropriate nowadays; weird question. What is the problem you’re actually trying to solve here? Do you want to iterate _grapheme clusters_? There are [proposals](//github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-v-flag) for this, but in this case, here’s a hint: `ɔ` (U+0254 LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN O) is of the class “Letter, Lowercase”, and U+0303 COMBINING TILDE is a character of the class “Mark, Nonspacing”. Therefore, this substring can be matched by the regex `/\p{L}\p{Mn}?/gu`.

Comment: Is `Array.from("iuyaɑãoɔɔ̃eεɛ̃øœœ̃əfvszʃʒlrpbmtdnkgɲjwɲ".matchAll(/\p{L}\p{Mn}?/gu), ([ match ]) => match)` what you’re looking for? Note that using anything other than Unicode isn’t possible in JavaScript. [The answer by Leo Lucas](/a/75346538/4642212) has almost certainly been generated by ChatGPT, which is [banned](/help/gpt-policy) on Stack Overflow. Do not trust this answer.

Answer (score -1):

It really doesn't seem like there really is a way to have a character ɔ̃ without any library... One simple solution will be to simply check to next character if there ever is a ɔ, and if it is a ~, then I will know this means ɔ̃. Thanks everyone for the answers and comments!